# WP VS SDK 2012 with 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Does Windows Phone 2012 SDK supports Windows Phone 8.1 as a device emulator ?
Also,
If on updating from WP 8.0 to WP 8.1 the app that was installed by SDK on 8.0 will be migrated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nop, Visual Studio 2012 has only the SDK for WP 8 application development. If you really wanted to upgrade an app from 8 to 8.1 you got to have VS2013.

For more just the requirements here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx

Hope it helps!